# Google Chrome not letting ASP.NET Chart Controls render. Throws Error " Website sent an invalid response"!

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, webchartcontrol

I am trying to show a chart control, it works fine in IE but it is throwing error "Website sent an invalid response" when loads up in Google Chrome. Suggestions are appreciated. Please help. Thank you. Below is the chart code:

```
 <asp:Chart ID="Chart_1" runat="server" BorderlineColor="Black" style="top: 22px; left: 7000px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; bottom: 280px; width: 320px; height: 305px;" Visible="False">
        <Titles>
    <asp:Title Font="Lucida Sans Unicode, 11pt" Name="Title1" 
        Text="Calender Days to Make Repair">
    </asp:Title>
</Titles>
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line" Color="Black"></asp:Series>
        </Series>
                <BorderSkin SkinStyle="Emboss"></BorderSkin> 
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"  BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White" BackColor="lightblue" ShadowColor="Transparent" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true">
                 <AxisX LineColor="Red">
                     <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" /> 
                 <MajorGrid LineColor="LightGray" />
                 </AxisX>

                <AxisY LineColor="Red">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" /> 
                <MajorGrid LineColor="LightGray" />
                </AxisY>

                <Area3DStyle Rotation="30" Perspective="30" Inclination="15" IsRightAngleAxes="False" WallWidth="0" IsClustered="False" />

            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: If you need help with your code, you will need to share some of it with us.

Comment: Code works fine. As everything works and functions well in IE, just that Google Chrome is not letting Chart Control render is the issue.

Comment: code added pls see